# Sprites flicker in Andengine

Tags: java, android, andengine

I want to move some sprites from left to right with a constant slow speed. I have first tried `RatioResolutionPolicy` but I saw sprites were flickering a lot. Then I have changed resolutionpolicy to `FixedResolutionPolicy`, defined sprite textures as bitmap, scaled them and made sprites by these textures (for more detail: [click here](https://github.com/edbartley/AndEngine---Texture-Source-From-Bitmap/blob/master/source.java)). This is better than first method but not completely good. I use `setx()` for moving sprites. When I change `x` positon for example by `2 pixels` for each frame there is no problem. But for different devices that have different resolutions I must multiply `2` by a ratio. In this case sprites are flickering again, not much but it is annoying for me.

Comment: post some code. How do you instantiate your camera? How exactly are you moving your sprites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that this wasn't about Andengine, it was about opengl. Solution for this problem is this wonderful tool:
https://github.com/gemserk/imageprocessing

Answer (score 0):

code for camera is below

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        Point size = new Point();
        w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        V.CAMERA_WIDTH = size.x;
        V.CAMERA_HEIGHT = size.y;
    } else {
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        V.CAMERA_WIDTH = d.getWidth();
        V.CAMERA_HEIGHT = d.getHeight();
    }

    if (V.CAMERA_HEIGHT/V.CAMERA_WIDTH>480f/860f){
        V.CAMERA_HEIGHT=V.CAMERA_WIDTH*480f/860f;
    }

    else {
        V.CAMERA_WIDTH=V.CAMERA_HEIGHT*860f/480f;
    }

    V.ratio=V.CAMERA_HEIGHT/480f;

    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, V.CAMERA_WIDTH, V.CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FixedResolutionPolicy((int)V.CAMERA_WIDTH, (int)V.CAMERA_HEIGHT),
            this.mCamera);

    return engineOptions;
}
```

for moving sprites:

```
this.wallPosX -= this.speed;
```

```
this.setX(Math.round(this.wallPosX));
```

speed is a floating point varibale and it gets 4.4651165 for 1280x720 screen resolution. If I set it as an integer than there is no flickering, but this time sprite speed differs from device to device.

Comment: Well, why don't you just set one resolution for all devices like it is supposed to be in andEngine? Set it as 800x480

Comment: I think you say to choose RatioResolutionPolicy. But as I said before, sprites with slow speed flicker a lot on that one.

Comment: yes, but try different resolutions like 800x480, not 860x480. Maybe there is a problem with bad resolution

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said. I have two android devices, one is a 800x480 phone and other is a 1024x600 tablet. Program works perfect on phone, but still flickers on tablet.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. Please put this text as an update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many screen sizes and screen ratio's for android phones.

Use the Cropped Resolution Policy created by jgibbs. Follow Martin Varga's tutorial to get an understanding on how it works and how to implement it.
It works wonders.

[Original from jgibbs](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/targeting-multiple-display-resolutions-t6794.html#p29955)

I recommend [Martin's Tutorial](http://android.kul.is/2013/10/andengine-tutorial-dealing-with-screen-sizes.html)

You shouldn't be worried about micro managing entities positional co-ordinates to suit every and any possible screen size.
I'm not sure this will fix the flickering though, that may be some other problem not related to your camera

Comment: Thanks for your  interest. I have solved this problem by this tool: https://github.com/gemserk/imageprocessing

Comment: Thanks, that may fix some problems in the future for me. You should submit an answer and mark it as the correct answer. It could help more people and give you more points on stack overflow.